# how to convert a plain text public key to der in openssl

Tags: c++, c, openssl

how to convert the the following pubkey to der encoded public key?
thanks, I saw i2d_PUBKEY maybe for it, but I don't know how to.

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>

uint8_t *pubkey = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

get_pubkey_function(&pubkey, &len);
printf(pubkey);
/* this step will print out 
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE+GmnZ1UZqKfa81Yh0CG6huQPhYON
Q0W7AE4whuX+oUOg+BewYSOLUwj5zfwRB3i7T07HoltPfAOYeHI57Oe7jA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
*/
```

Comment: For a start, decide on a language to code in. Read the descriptions of the tags you applied for reference. None of the above is even remotely valid code in either language, too. Why are you not using according tools to do the conversion? You could also study how they do it to get an insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
    EVP_PKEY *public_key = NULL;
    BIO *bio = NULL;
    bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *)pubkey, -1);
    PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bio, &public_key, NULL, NULL);
    EXPECT_TRUE(public_key);
```

am I right?